# PHP str_replace not replacing quotes

Tags: php

Hello I have the following code witch scans a string and is suppose to replace any double quotes with `&quot;`. The problem is it finds the double quotes, replaces them with `&quot;` but it also adds an extra `&quot;` to the end of it. it dosnt actually replace the quote. I dont understand what im doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
        $lineOcc31 = substr_count($text, '"');

        if($lineOcc31 < '1'){
            $text = $text;
        }else{
            $text = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $text);
        }
```

Comment: did you try `'"', "'"`?

Comment: Why bother counting the instances of quotes before replacing them?

Comment: Just use [`htmlspecialchars`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It's what it's for.

Comment: your acceptance record is questionable btw.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'something with a " in it';
echo htmlentities($string);
```

Output:
something with a `&quot;` in it

See it here https://3v4l.org/afrNi

Comment: you need to wrap the code with ticks `\`` that's why it did not format it properly. I edited.

Comment: welcome. You don't need 3 ticks, just tick(code)tick. and yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you should change str_replace `&quot;` with `''`:

```
<?php
$text = '"String"';
$lineOcc31 = substr_count($text, '"');

if($lineOcc31 > '1'){
    $text = str_replace('"', '', $text);
    echo $text;
}
?>
```